# Изучение С++ с нуля

Tags: c++

Ребят, помогите, начал изучать С++ с нуля. Программировать начал на Visual C++ express 2008. И столкнулся с такой проблемой, что везде есть свой стиль программирования.

Т.е. кто-то начинает свою программу с библиотеки `#include <iostream.h>`, а кто-то с `#include "stdafx.h"`. Учусь я по видео урокам на youtube.com, вот [ссылка](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2GCkeTwlj5g&feature=BFa&list=PL416C511D02A4E585&lf=plpp_video) на одно из видео.

Подскажите, это правильно или нет. Или лучше стоит начинать как-то по другому? В институте сессия горит из за этого С++, год до этого не учил, а сейчас задница настала. Весь интернет облазил и не могу найти задачку по двумерному массиву со вводом данных. Вернее могу, но там настолько сильно отличается стиль, от того на котором я учусь, что у меня даже Visual C++ его не хочет воспринимать.

Вот одна из программ кстати, которую мне нужно сдать. Посмотрите, м. б. кто поможет.

> Разработать программу для работы с двумерными массивами. Ее функции:
>
> - считывание элементов двумерного массива из файла (txt), где в первой строке можно задавать размерность массива;
> - нахождение индексов максимального и минимального элемента методом последовательного поиска;
> - определение среднего арифметического элементов, суммы элементов по строкам и столбцам;
> - вывод полученных данных на экран.

Comment: Вот пример задачи как я ввожу данные в массив на codeBlocks, как проделать такое же только на Visual studio C++
Самый главный вопрос как задать массив и какие библиотеки нужно использовать.

Вот пример int aMatrix[3][3]={0};
 for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
    for (int j=0; j<3; j++)
       {
        cout<<"Vvedite elementi massiva"<<endl;
        cin>>aMatrix[i][j]
       }

Comment: Я начинал изучать C++ в школе, нам дали программу обучения, где объясняют такие вещи как "Ввод в консоль" заканчивая сложными структурами данных, вам советую посмотреть вот это программу обучения, вместе с заданиями по пройденному материалу.[-----> Программа обучения <-----](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0n_GNXyxYwYY1VzMGNhNUJoUEU)

Answer (score 3):

из `#include "stdafx.h"` начинают свои программы те, кто пишет в visual studio. Там спрятаны важные для студии "данные". Если не оставить в самом верху, то студия может не собрать проект или собрать не совсем так, как нужно.

`#include <iostream.h>` лучше не включать в свою программу - это старый стиль программирования. На данный момент рекомендуется использовать новый стиль - `#include <iostream>` (Для большинства стандартных заголовков есть новые эквиваленты).

А вот читать как массив? Одномерный умеете? если да, то проблем с двумерным не должно быть никаких. Просто два вложенных цикла.

Answer (score 3):

stdafx.h - это предкомпилированный заголовок. Он позволяет ускорить компиляцию, путём выноса в него неизменяемого кода, например библиотек. Работает только в Visual C++. Для маленьких учебных проектов он не нужен. Если тебе попался код, использующий его, вынеси его содержимое в сам cpp-файл и удали. Чтобы компилятор не ругался, нужно отключить его использование в настройках проекта.

> считывание элементов двумерного массива из файла (txt), где в первой строке можно задавать размерность массива;

```
std::ifstream file("file.txt");
int n, m;
file >> n >> m;

//Создаём динамически двумерный массив и считываем информацию:
int* data=new int[n*m]; 
int** array=new int*[m];
for(int i=0; i<m; i++)
{
    array[i]=data+i*n;
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
        file >> array[i][j];
}
```

> нахождение индексов максимального и минимального элемента методом последовательного поиска;

```
int minValue=INT_MAX, maxValue=INT_MIN;
for(int i=0; i<m; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
        if(array[i][j]<minValue) minValue=array[i][j];
        if(array[i][j]>maxValue) maxValue=array[i][j];
    }
```

> определение среднего арифметического элементов, суммы элементов по строкам и столбцам;

Не понял, что надо делать тут. Среднее арифметическое чего?

> вывод полученных данных на экран.

```
cout << minValue << ' ' << maxValue << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Хедеры по большей части все равно как вставлять. Есть какие-то исключения, но редко. Я еще по жизни не сталкивался.

Answer (score 0):

Чтение двумерного массива целых из файла:

```
std::ifstream file("from");

// Объявить переменные для хранения размерностей
int n, m;

// Считать размерности в переменные
file >> n >> m;

// Объявить и разместить массив для хранения цифр
std::vector<std::vector<int>> numbers(n, std::vector<int>(m));

// В цикле считать цифры в массив
for(int k = 0, i = 0, j = 0; k < (n * m) && (file >> numbers[i][j]);)
{
    ++k
    i = k % n;
    j = k / n;
}
```

Дальнейшее в качестве упражнения

Comment: Писать такие циклы for - плохой тон программирования. И вообще, новичку это будет непонятно. Неужели нельзя было написать нормальный двойной цикл?

Answer (score 0):

Вообще можно учится и по видео но самое лучшее это книги! Вот тебе примеры:
"С++ Шаг за Шагом(Гербердт Шилд)","Эффективное программирование на с++(Э.Кениг)"

P.S
А что касается стилей ты немного не понимаешь потому что iostream и stdafx.h 
это разные вещи одна библиотека а другой заголовок для компиляции файла.
Но стили правда бывают разные потому что можно написать iostream.h а можно просто iostream но тут кто как привык уже.

Comment: Стиль программирования не повязан с iostream и iostream.h, это одинаковые библиотек но одна из них новая (iostream), а другая устаревшая и очень редко используется. По книжкам бистро не обучится, там много воды в большинстве случаев. Самоё главное это практика, если ты не поймёшь как это работает, тебе никакая книжка это не разталкует, ты должен на ошибках учится и если что-то не понятно обращаться на ru.stackoverflow.com. Разные стили это когда один пишет { в начале строки, а другой в конце преведущей ну и таму подобное.